# Counting the number of comparisons in quicksort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have a homework where I need to implement quicksort with three partition strategies and count the number of comparisons for each strategy.

for simplicity, we are asked to add `m-1` to the count every time we do a recursive call on an array of length  `m`.

my code is always returning a negative number and  it is not an integer overflow issue.
I used `long long int` and I still have it, and there is no way the number of comparisons would grow that much, so there is something wrong with the way I am counting.

I tested the code on a 100000 element array using `is_sorted` after calling my implementation and it passed, so the the sorting is correct
here is my code:

```
long quick_sort (vector <int>& A, int l , int r){
    static  long count = 0;
    if ( r<= l)
        return 0;

    //partition
    int i = partition(A, l, r);

    //quicksort left
    int amount = ( ((i -1) -l) >= 0 ?
                            ((i-1) -l) :
                                    0);
    count += amount;
    quick_sort (A,l, i-1);

    //quicksort right
    amount = ((r - (i +1)) >= 0 ?
                        (r - (i +1)) :
                                  0);
    count += amount;
    quick_sort (A,i+1, r);

    return count;

}
```

Comment: As a suggestion: Count the comparison where you do them, which is the line `int i = partition(A, l, r);`. Much easier and less error-prone.

Answer (score 2):

Change your test value to hold correct expressions:

```
count += ( (i-1)-l >= 0 ? (i-1)-l : 0 )
quick_sort (A,l, i-1);
```

and

```
count += ( r-(i+1) >= 0 ? ...
quick_sort (A,i+1, r);
```

Comment: `(i-1) - l == i -1 - l` and `r - i - 1 == r - (i+1)`, right ?

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi Not necessarily. Just try it my way.

Comment: it worked !!! , though this is against the laws of math. :D
can you explain why that worked ?

Comment: Actually I can't spot why did you get the wrong result, but the solution is always to not assume anything. Maybe you had a typo and you fixed it inadvertently when you edited the code.

Comment: actually, it didn't work>
I will post the code after putting the parentheses as you said, it is still giving negative numbers

Answer (score 0):

Your static variable is probably not being set to 0 when you expect it to. Make it a global variable.

Also, why are you doing the work when you make the recursive calls instead of when the call is made? It would be so much easier to do it one time instead of two.